# Как получить доступ к View-элементам активити из адаптера

Tags: android, listview

Есть `Activity`, на ней `TextView` и `ListView`. В пункте `ListView` кнопка, которая обрабатывается в адаптере. Как из адаптера получить доступ к `TextView`  `Activity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете хранить ссылку на `TextView` прямо в адаптере, например, сделать сеттер у адаптера:

```
public class MyAdapater extends ArrayAdapter {
    private TextView activityTextView;

    public void setActivityTextView(TextView textView) {
        activityTextView = textView;
    }

    ...
    ...
    //делаете с TextView, что угодно в вашем getView()
}
```

Затем в `Activity`, вызываете этот метод:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyAdapter adapter = ...;//инициализация адаптера
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    adapter.setActivityTextView(textView);
    ...
}
```

Comment: О, да, хранить activityTextView(который также содержит ссылку на активити - getContext() ) и неявно его менять из левого класса намного лучше чем хранить ссылку на активити :)

Comment: Вообще не факт, что getContext() содержит ссылку на активити.

Answer (score 0):

Есть много методов, некоторые из них очень простые но "костыльные", другие получше но требуют написать чуть больше кода.

Я так понимаю вопрос возник из-за того что у вас адаптер вынесен в отдельный класс, иначе вы бы напрямую могли менять `TextView`.

Как вариант это сделать в активити метод типа `public void updateText(String text)`

Далее передавать ваше активити в конструктор адаптера, и вызывать метод `updateText();`

Comment: Хранить ссылку на активити в адаптере не лучший метод, тогда обязательно нужно сделать ее `WeakReference<Activity> activity`.